# Automatically generating IDs with Ember & Firebase

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, firebase

I'm trying to generate ID's for a model. Ember documentation says that Ember automatically generates IDs for its models.

But when I pass data to Firebase and try to display it, the IDs return undefined. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="stack">
  <div class='stack'>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span12" style="text-align:center; margin: 0 auto;">

          {{#if isEditing}}
            {{partial 'stack/edit'}}
            <button {{action 'doneEditing'}}>Done</button>
          {{else}}
            <button {{action 'edit'}}>Edit</button>
          {{/if}}

        <h1>{{stack.title}}</h1>
        <h2>at {{stack.date}} <small class='muted'>({{format-date date}})</small></h2>

        <hr>

        <div class='intro'>
          {{stack.location}}
        </div>

        <div class='below-the-fold'>
          {{stack.details}}
        </div>
```

...

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
  this.resource('stacks');
  this.resource('stack', {path: 'stacks/:stack_id'}, function() {
        this.route('edit');
        this.resource('comments', function() {
            this.route('new');
        })
    }); 
    this.route('create');
  this.resource('groups');
  });

App.StackRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return stacks.findBy('id', params.stack_id);
    }
});



App.CreateController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    init: function() {
        this.set('stack', Ember.Object.create());
    },
    actions: {
        createStack: function() {
            var newStack = this.store.createRecord('stack', {
                title: this.get('stack.title'),
                location: this.get('stack.location'),
                date: new Date().getTime(),
                details: this.get('stack.details'),
            });

            newStack.save();

            alert('newStack.title' + " is ready!");
        },

        cancelStackCreation: function() {
            this.sendAction('cancel');
            alert("Canceled stack creation.");
        },
    }
});


App.StackController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    isEditing: false,

    actions: {
        edit: function() {
            this.set('isEditing', true);
        },

        doneEditing: function() {
            this.set('isEditing', false);
        },
    } 
});
```

Comment: Can you see what id firebase is giving?

Comment: Firebase should auto-assign the ids for you.

Comment: @Bloomfield Yes it generates id's like "JkDmhXBoXbpvFnYd3hX" 

I've gotten the data to display but they aren't linked to appropriate ids. How do I link to url for each id?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `this.store.createRecord()` you have an "option" to have an `id` autogenerated (see [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L313)) Ultimately though, that responsibility is delegated to an `adapter`. If your adapter has `generateIdForRecord()` method - this will be used to create an id. So, for example, `FixtureAdapter` implements this method as follows (see [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/fixture_adapter.js#L128)):

```
generateIdForRecord: function(store) {
  return "fixture-" + counter++;
}
```

If you are using the `FirebaseAdapter`([this one](https://github.com/thomasboyt/ember-firebase-adapter/blob/master/lib/firebase/adapter.js)) it doesn't look like that's generating an `id`, so you would need to extend it and do it yourself if you really want this functionality to happen on the client. But you need to really ask yourself if you do. ;) The default `RestAdapter` doesn't generate ids for its models either.

Comment: Thanks. I am using FirebaseAdapter. I'm ok with Firebase generating id's for me, but I just don't know how to link to the id's url to display appropriate data...

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by using

```
{{#link-to 'stack.index' this.stack.id}}
```

I was able to link to specific url based on the id.