# Ember createRecord not creating an id

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to create a "note" record with createRecord.  When I pass it into my action, it properly creates the record, but only creates the "body" attribute I pass in, and not the id or timestamps.  It does, however, create these attributes after I refresh.  My problem is that I want it to create these as soon as I click my "create" button, so I can sort in descending order, and be able to delete the note without having to refresh each time.

My controller:

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    newNote: function() {
      var body = this.get('noteCopy');
      var note = this.store.createRecord('note', { body: body });
      this.set('noteCopy', '');
      note.save();
    },
    deleteNote: function(id) {
      this.store.find('note', id).then(function(note) {
        note.deleteRecord();
        note.save();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

My template:

```
{{textarea placeholder="Add a note!" value=noteCopy class='newNoteArea' 

autofocus=true}}<br>
<button class='createNoteButton'{{action 'newNote'}} style='font-size:2em'>Save Note</button><br><br>
<br>
{{#each note in model}}
  <div class="noteShow">
      {{note.body}}<br>
  <img src="assets/erase.gif" alt="" class='deleteNoteButton'{{action 'deleteNote' note.id}} style='width:4em'/>
</div>
{{/each}}
{{outlet}}
```

My server does the sorting properly once the note creates the timestamps attributes... But since I get

> id: null, body: "some body", created_at: undefined, updated_at: undefined

every time I create a new note, it doesn't do anything it's supposed to, until I refresh.  It occurred to me that this may be a problem with promises, but after trying to implement some .success() and .then() lines, I have a feeling this isn't the case.

Forgive me if this is a newbie question, but I'm still quite new to Ember.  Any input is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: *it doesn't do anything it's supposed to* What is it supposed to do? As a start, instead of passing `note.id` in the action form the template, just pass `note`, then in your action handler, skip the `this.store.find` and just do the `deleteRecord` immediately.

Comment: Can you post your `note` model definition?

Comment: See the following http://stackoverflow.com/a/29018979/908842

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I got rid of note.id in the template action, which fixed my delete action (since it's no longer trying to find the id by its null value).  

The other thing I want to do is to push the note to the beginning of my notes list, so the most recent one shows up first. Since createRecord doesn't fill in the timestamps immediately, its created_at property is undefined, and therefore at the end of the list until I refresh the page.  Once I do refresh, it fills in the property and jumps to the beginning of my notes collection.

Answer (score 1):

The `id` is given to you by the API server you POST to. You can retrieve the `id` after the creation was successful.

```js
var newJob = jobController.store.createRecord('job', {
  status: 'requested',
  message: '',
});
console.log(newJob);

newJob.save().then(() => {
    console.log('Job ID ', newJob.id, ' created.');
  }.bind(jobController), (err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  }.bind(jobController)
);
```